# Nested eager loading sequelize ( belongsTo and belongsToMany in a same query )

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

On a NodeJS server (8.6.0) with Express (4.15.2) , Sequelize (3.30.0) and Mysql, 
I'm facing the following "simple" use-case :
( Don't pay attention to table name ;))
I have this model defined :

Child.belongsTo(Son)
Child.belongsToMany(Parents)

```
tableName: 'Child',
classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
        this.belongsToMany(models.Parent, { as :{ singular: 'child',                 plural: 'children' }, through: 'Parent_Child'} );

        this.belongsTo(models.Son, {foreignKey : 'fkSon', as :'son' });
    }
```

I want to get in a same query all related models to Child.
My model definition works fine. I can get Parent related to Child and Son related to Child but not both.

Here the query I try to run unfortunately (inspired by sequelize doc http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#nested-eager-loading

```
models.Child.findAll({
include : [{model : models.Son, as:'son',
include : [{model : models.Parent, as : 'children', through:    'Parent_Child' , require : true}]

}]
```

I have the following error : Error: Parent (children) is not associated to Son!

Many Thanks in advance :)